# How do I create a module/class that calls all single-classed modules in a directory?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, class

I'm pretty new to the python scene, but not to programming. I'm looking to create a class that calls all modules in a directory (each module will only have a single class) and can't quite yet wrap my head around class-to-class implementation. To roughly illustrate, I have the following directory structure

```
-__init__.py
-addon.py
-lib/
    -__init__.py
    -sources/
             -__init__.py
             -source1scraper.py
             -source2scraper.py
             -source3scraper.py
```

I want to have a class I can call that will run each result (lists)

A rough idea of the Sources class would go like so

```
import threading

class Sources():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Sources = []

    def getSources(self):
        sourceDict = []
        for package, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__): sourceDict.append((name, is_pkg))
        sourceDict = [i[0] for i in sourceDict if i[1] == False]
        threads = []
        for source in sourceDict:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.getLinks(source))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

    def getLinks(self, source):
        self.Links = []
```

**Problem 1** here is I don't know where I'd place this class. Maybe it would go in the `__init__.py` of the `sources` directory?

**Problem 2** here is I'm unsure how to call each source, get back the links, and append to the existing list of links from the other sources that have already been called.

**Problem 3** here is I don't know how to correctly thread the processes, so the scrapers run concurrently.

Then comes the scraper.py files. Here's a rough idea of the scraper.py files' structure

```
import requests
import re
class Source(Sources.Source):
    def __init__(self):
        self.full_link = 'http://www.blahblah.com/path/to/content'
        self.base_link = 'http://www.blahblah.com' #for appending symbolic links
        self.regex = '<a href="([^"]+)" rel="nofollow"'

    def links(self):
        try:
            links = []
            source_html = client.request(self.full_link)
            match = re.compile(self.regex).findall(source_html)
            return links
        except:
            return links
```

**Problem 4** is I don't know what needs to be specified between the class' parenthesis where I currently have `class Source(Sources.Source):`.

Any advice on how to correctly implement what I'm looking to do would be greatly appreciated. Am I even close?

Comment: You should take a look at the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module for all your dynamic importing needs, but before you go down that path explain to a rubber duck why are you making this so complicated?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that module to see if I could include it if I can't figure anything else out. To answer your question, there's an easier way? I'm genuinely curious and all ears to hear it. I'm here to learn all I can. If that was simply a question pertaining to me being a beginner, then my answer is because I've always gone for a large project when learning a new language because 1) Working towards something I'd actually use makes me want to do it more and 2) I like to really challenge myself and keep my brain busy :)

Comment: No, I'm implying that whatever you're doing - you're needlessly complicating it. From experience, 99 out of 100 projects that reach out for dynamic loading or attempt at working around a languages' limits-by-design - don't really need it and and, at best, it's a waste of time for the developers, at worst it turns into a maintenance nightmare... Thus, I suggested a bit of [rubberducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to make sure this is something your project absolutely needs.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Could you possibly suggest another approach. If possible, I'd like to keep the scrapers in individual files as each is going to be different.

Comment: And to give a bit of background where I got the idea. I got the code from https://github.com/noobsandnerds/noobsandnerds/tree/master/plugin.video.elysium/resources/lib/sources/__init__.py and https://github.com/noobsandnerds/noobsandnerds/blob/master/plugin.video.elysium/resources/lib/sources/ddlvalley_mv_tv.py

Comment: Place your scrapers in different files, absolutely, but don't load them dynamically - instead import them into your `sources/__init__.py` and add them to its `__all__` list and everybody will be able to access them in pretty much any way. As for that code that inspired you - that's actually rather bad example, to understand why I suggest you to watch [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). If I have some time tomorrow I'll see to write some pseudo-code to give you an idea how you can achieve what (I think) you're trying to achieve in a simple, manageable way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for letting me know that the code isn't a good example to follow. I would've never known that. I'd really appreciate that pseudo-code whenever you have the chance. Also, that way I can provide you with credit for helping me so much. One more question though, pertaining to placing all the files in the `__init__.py`'s `__all__` list. If I'm having to put all of the filenames in that variable why wouldn't I just use `from lib.sources import *`? Isn't that accomplishing the same thing?